# how i can configure my sharepoint web application to only be accessable from https

Tags: 2013, deployment, web-application, configuration, https

I'm working on a SharePoint 2013 web application. Currently the web application can be accessed using *http* only and if I try to access it using *https* I will get "Page not found" error".

Our customer have asked us to modify this and allow accessing the web application ONLY using **https**.

Can anyone advice me on how I can achieve this?